# Powershell - Read an environment Variable value and set the value in a Yaml file

Tags: powershell

In a Powershell session, I'm trying to read the value of the VAULT_TOKEN environment variable to set the value for a key (X-Vault-Token), and then save the output to a yaml file.The VAULT_TOKEN environment variable has a valid value, but I'm not able to get that value set for `X-Vault-Token: $(env:VAULT_TOKEN)` .

```
 # Create a YAML Document 
$RawYaml = @'
integration_name: com.monitor.sql
variables:
  Content:
    vault:
      http:
        url: https://vault.service.consul/v1/xyz/mssqlnr
        headers:
          X-Vault-Token: $(env:VAULT_TOKEN)
 '@

$RawYaml | out-File C:\Users\Public\Downloads\config.yaml
```

---

I did refer to the link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cpowershell&viewFallbackFrom=vsts#set-in-script), and tried different options without any success.  Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not with the way you invoke the variable but with the type of here-string you used, in PS when you use '' to define text, it does not expand any variable, example:

```
PS> $test =@'
>> $(5+5)
>> '@
PS> $test
$(5+5)
```

you need to use double quotes ", example:

```
PS> $test2 =@"
>> $(5+5)
>> "@
PS> $test2
10
```

so in you case it'll be like this:

```
# Create a YAML Document 
$RawYaml = @"
integration_name: com.monitor.sql
variables:
  Content:
    vault:
      http:
        url: https://vault.service.consul/v1/xyz/mssqlnr
        headers:
          X-Vault-Token: $env:VAULT_TOKEN
 "@

$RawYaml | out-File C:\Users\Public\Downloads\config.yaml
```

That should fix it, good luck.

Comment: I don't see how `$(env:anything)` would be valid. Shouldn't that be `$($env:anything)`?

Comment: Thank you Roque. It worked for me !  Voo, this is my new setting  X-Vault-Token: $env:VAULT_TOKEN

Comment: I was not able to get this to work with the "@"; however, removing those allowed me to inject variables into my "yaml" file and then the output line worked nicely. Thanks!